# What is a good way to cluster points on a map using mongodb and nodejs?

Tags: google-maps, maps

Are there any node.js modules that do what http://www.maptimize.com/ does? I have many thousands of points on a map and obviously showing each one is very messy.

Technology I am using: node.js , mongodb, express, angular js, and google maps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer could be the [Google Maps Android Marker Clustering Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering), so have a look into it.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I am working with PCs and not android though.

Comment: ok, sorry about not noticing that, anyways, you could maybe search with "google maps clustering" keywords on google, it appears to give some results that might also work on your environment.